# Real php form of blade templates

Tags: php, laravel

i have figured out some blade templates (laravel) like `@section('title', getOption('app_name') . ' - Login')
@section('body')` as its real php formis `<?php $__env->startSection('title', getOption('app_name') . ' - login'); ?>
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>` . and these are correct ,,

But i wanna know the real php form of `@extends(layouts.app)` .

anybody got an Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

All of your compiled blade views are stored in `storage/framework/views/` if you want to dig around and try to understand how Laravel turns a blade template into php.

It looks like your views define the sections first, then pass them to the layout 
 as variables. Inside your view which `@extends(layouts.app)` you might see this at the *end*:

```
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.app', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

The sections were defined *before* that line and passed as variables. When you look inside the layout itself, you'll see things like this for including each of those sections:

```
<?php echo $__env->yieldContent('content'); ?>
```

Comment: its seems like your code is acting like section view, not extends

Comment: The sections are defined *first* in the compiled views. The templates you extend are actually built last, and given the variables that the sections defined as arguments.